# MKMapView Google issue

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I have created MKMapView, and instead of tagging "Google" it showing Legal. Please can anyone explain me why it showing Legal label.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they no longer use Google for maps. They use Apples own mapping service.